# jQuery- Whats a good way to use selectors after already making a selection?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

So I have an HTML page I need to parse while in a chrome extension, where the table I need to get is in this structure:

```
<table class="center"><tr><td>
  <table>
    <tr><th>...</th></tr>
    <tr><td>
      <table>data to process</table>
```

```js
var $data = $("table.center tbody tr").first().next();
$data.children("td")
     .children("table")
     .children("tbody")
     .children("tr")
```

I'm not too good with jquery, but this was the only way I could find to get me each of the tr lines so i could process the data.
surely there is a better way to do this... The JS is getting injected into the page as I browse to it if that makes any difference. Mind you the tbody isn't in the source, but i can't get the data without it.

Thanks

Comment: I don't get your actual question, what is the problem?

Comment: How about `$("table.center table table tr")`?

Comment: Your initial selector will find all `<tr>` elements within the `table.center` element, the use of `first()` (I *think*, parsing this in my head) should select the `<tr>` containing the first `<table>` descendant but you don't seem to post what the `next()` should select.

Comment: I have to get the 2nd <tr> tag. I found the .first().next() method on stack to get it reliably. Unless there is a better way to do that as well I don't know.
@Scaramouche - I want to figure out better way to do what I have posted thats all.

Comment: In that case, `$("table.center table tr:nth-child(2) table tr")` or `$("table.center table tr").eq(1).find("table tr")`

Comment: nested tables usually points to your code being semantically incorrect

Comment: @ChrisG- Neither of those two options are working for me. Pete- Not my code. Just me having to deal with it.